# printing a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, printing, graphics2d

I am trying to print a JPanel called comp .It contains a tabel and some labels.When ever I

print the comp the table goes beyond the page's width. I really don't understand why this is

happening . Need a solution to this problem

Here is the print method I am using:

```
private void printCard(){

PrinterJob printjob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
printjob.setJobName(" personal card ");

printjob.setPrintable (new Printable() {      
     public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){                  

         pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

         if (pageNum > 0){
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
         }

         Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
         g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
         g2.translate( 0f, 0f );
         comp.paint(g2);

         return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
     }
});

if (printjob.printDialog() == false)
   return;

try {
   printjob.print();
}
catch (PrinterException ex) {
   System.out.println("NO PAGE FOUND."+ex);
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try printing in landscape orientation.

Comment: Is it ironic that he doesn't accept his *own* answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resize the table and the labels. This should work.